# How would I use tampermonkey to automatically enable longer sets of numbers

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

```
<input type="text" name="turns" size="3" maxlength="4" value="99">
```

The max length there is 4. Im wondering what I could put into tampermonkey to make it automatically change max length to something longer, say 6.

Comment: The max length where?

Comment: Fixed, code stuff didnt show up

Comment: Use the `{}` tool in the SO editor to mark code.

Comment: Loop over all the `input` elements, and do `element.setAttribute('maxlength', 6);`.

Comment: And how would you tell someone to do that, if they had no idea what you mean haha

Comment: Learning Javascript is a prerequisite for using TamperMonkey.

Comment: SO is not for getting people to program for you, it's for getting help with your programs. You need to make some effort to do it, and if you can't get it working you should post what you tried, and we'll help you fix it and learn where you went wrong.

Comment: ok then help me understand what you mean when you say loop over them?

Comment: Something like this: `for (var i = inputs; i < inputs.length; i++) { do stuff with inputs[i] }`

Comment: You might also want to look into using jQuery, it can simplify things like this.

Comment: With jQuery you would write `$("input[type=text]").attr("maxlength", 6)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I wanted to do *exactly* what you ask, I would say

```
var i,myInputs = document.getElementsByName("turns");

for (i=0;i<myInputs.length;i++) {
  if ( (myInputs[i].tagName.toLowerCase()=="input")
    && (myInputs[i].type.toLowerCase()=="text")
  ) myInputs[i].setAttribute("maxlength","6");
}
```

This is a lot of code; that's because there might be more than one element with the same name, and they might not be `<input>` elements, or they might have a type other than `"text"`.  If you don't care about potential errors, just say

```
document.getElementsByName("turns")[0].maxLength = 6;
```

which will work fine as long as the HTML you refer to appears exactly once on the page.

Comment: Thinking about it, just do `try{document.getElementsByName("turns").forEach(function(x){x.maxLength=6})} catch(e) {}`.

Comment: The first one you put in worked great, thanks a lot!